# Reference to calling viewcontroller / Method depending on type of calling view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have a view controller, that is called from several other view controllers. This view controller contains a UITextField, which collects different information, depending on which view controller has called it.
The information has to be stored after it was collected. To be as independent as possible, the method to store the information should be located in the calling view controller. 
Thus, I use the following code in the method to collect the information:

```
- (void) collectContent
{
    NSString *info = [textField text];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NewValueA" object:info];

    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In the calling view controller, I have the following line in its init method:

```
- (id) init
{
    ...
    if (self)
    {
        ...
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(storeNewValueA) name:"NewValueA" object:nil];
    }
return self;
}
```

But now, I want to use this view controller from another view controller, to collect ValueB or ValueC. How do I reference the calling view controller to call a method for storing the collected value just there? I want to decide, that if the view controller was called from vcB, the entered value must have been valueB, an so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a protocol for this commonly used view controller and implement this protocol by the calling view controllers :

```
@protocol TextFieldViewControllerDelegate : NSObject {
    - (void)contentCollected;
}
```

In your text field (the common) view controller define a delegate property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<TextFieldViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

The calling view controller will set itself as the delegate and implement the needed method:

```
- (void) contentCollected:(NSString *)value
{
    // Store the value where needed
}
```

In the common (textfield) view controller notify the delegate when needed :

```
- (void) collectContent
{
    NSString *info = [textField text];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [_delegate contentCollected:info];

    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    _delegate = nil;
}
```

This way your common view controller does not need to know which view controller called it. Using the delegate the calling view controller will be notified.

Comment: I already thought about delegation and implementing a protocol. If I would do it this, I'd have a relatively tight coupling between the controllers. This is what I want to avoid...

Comment: This is not tight coupling as the common view controller does not know or care who is its delegate it just need the delegate to implement the protocol method to correctly be notified.

Comment: Yes, you are right! And by calling the delegate method I can pass any information I want - no matter, what kind it is!

Comment: exactly, and do not forget to set the delegate to self (the calling controller) before pushing the textfield controller

Answer (score 0):

Hm, if you want to persist this simple string even when the application was close, I would use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

Store the string:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"MyValue" ForKey:@"USER_DEFAULTS_VIEWCONTROLLER_VALUES"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Get the string:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"USER_DEFAULTS_VIEWCONTROLLER_VALUES"];
```

Comment: Though I woulddn't have a reference to the calling controller, this is exactly, what I try to acieve! Moreover, the view controller doesn't have tio know, who called him and really is loosely coupled... :-)

Comment: Nevertheless I have to know, which value to store, i.e. I have to call the method for the value that I stored in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Who calls whos method? :-) Does ViewControllerA call a selector of ViewControllerA or ViewControllerA->TextFieldViewController or even TextFieldViewController->TextFieldViewController ? :)